# 2D OpenGL in GLFW flickers

Tags: c++, opengl, nvidia, lag, glfw

I'm trying to create a 2D game using OpenGL. My helper libraries are GLFW, GLEW, SOIL (for images) and glm (for maths).

I've managed to draw a rectangle with a very simple texture on it. But when I try to move this rectangle it frequently has a little flicker (the timer between flickers is almost always the same), and the faster I move it, the more visible it becomes.

Another problem I have is I'm working on a laptop, and it renders fine with my integrated graphics (fine as in it works, it still stutters) but when I execute my program with my Nvidia graphics card it just shows my clearcolor, and nothing else, which is extremely odd. My sprite translation happens in the runCallback code (called in the main loop) and is just a multiplication of matrices. The result matrix is then fetched and used in the draw code. In the drawCallback theres just the DrawSprite function being called. Also I should note I'm using OpenGL 3.3 .

I'm sorry in advance for the rather large amount of code, but after extensive testing and trying a multitude of things i have no idea where my mistake lies...
If you would like to help me but need any more information, i will provide.

UPDATE:
Problem with Nvidia graphics card resolved, it was due to a wrong uniform parameter. But the stutter remains.

IMAGE LOADING CODE

```
SD_Texture::SD_Texture(const char * fileName)
{
texture = new GLuint;
unsigned char* data = SOIL_load_image(fileName, &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGB);
glGenTextures(1, (GLuint*)texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *((GLuint*)(texture)));

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

SOIL_free_image_data(data);
}

void SD_Texture::Bind()
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *(GLuint*)texture);
}
```

VAO SETUP CODE

```
void SD_Window::SetupVAO()
{
GLfloat vertices[] =
{
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5, 0.0f,      1.0, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      0.0f, 1.0f,
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      1.0f, 1.0f
};

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);



glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (GLvoid*)nullptr);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (GLvoid*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

DRAW CODE

```
void SD_Window::DrawSprite(SD_Sprite * sprite)
{
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
sprite->GetTexture()->Bind();
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ortho * sprite->GetTransform()));

glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glBindVertexArray(0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

MAIN LOOP CODE

```
void SD_Window::TakeControl(void (*runCallback)(float delta), void (*drawCallback)())
{

double currentTime;
double oldTime = 0.0f;

while (!ShouldClose())
{
    currentTime = glfwGetTime();

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawCallback();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    runCallback(currentTime - oldTime);
    oldTime = currentTime;

    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwDestroyWindow(window);
glfwTerminate();
}
```

VERTEX SHADER

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;

out vec2 sCoord;

uniform mat4 transform;

void main()
{
gl_Position = transform * vec4(position, 1.0f);

sCoord = vec2(texCoord.x, 1.0f - texCoord.y);
}
```

FRAGMENT SHADER

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 sCoord;

out vec4 color;

uniform sampler2D sTexture;

void main()
{
color = texture(sTexture, sCoord);
 }
```

Comment: To find the issue with the dedicated nvidea card, you should check for errors using glError(). For the movement part, have you tried a fixed timestep? Fixed timesteps are wrong but it might help you debug for now, however I can't see a problem with your timing code...

Comment: Thanks for your help! An "invalid operation" error on my graphics card taught me that my argument transformUniform in the call: glUniformMatrix4fv(transformUniform, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(ortho * sprite->GetTransform())); was actually not initialized! It was not set to the right uniform! Weird that it worked on integrated graphics. I still have the stutter problem though.

Comment: Great, its good practice to have glError calls in lots of places, but its a costly function, remember that. What have you tried so far to solve the stutter? Did you try the fixed timestep i mentioned? I've had problems on windows where certain timers didn't give me the resolution I wanted, and would sometimes return the same value twice, making the scene "stutter". I don't know the resolution of glfw timers though.

Comment: I have used std::chrono::high_resolution_clock and glfwGetTime(). Both yield the same result. I don't completely understand what you mean with a fixed timestamp? Do you mean i should only move my sprite when a certain time has passed?

Comment: No i mean instead of calling  runCallback(currentTime - oldTime); you just call runCallback(0.16) or something to that effect.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, but this didn't work as well.

Comment: You're better off submitting a new question I think, try to find out more about the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "flicker" ? Does the sprite disappear for one frame or does it look it is split in two pieces ?